# Angular Material 7 Drag and Drop x and y coordinates

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-material-7

I have a container with an element inside it.  I want to be able to drag the element to another location inside the container and see the new x and y coordinates (where x=0 and y=0 is the top left corner of the container).

I have a basic stackblitz set up at https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-6-mjrhg1, but it won't show the entire event object in the console ("object too large").  In my actual application, I can look through the entire event object, but I can't find any properties describing the new x and y locations.

The basic setup is this:

```
<div style="height: 200px; width=200px; background-color: yellow" class="container">
  <div 
    style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: red; z-index: 10" 
    cdkDrag 
    cdkDragBoundary=".container"
    (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnded($event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried some of the other events, but cdkDragEnded makes the most sense to me.

Any ideas what property to check to find the x and y coordinates, or should I be using a different event / approach?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the element that is being dragged from the `source` property on your `CdkDragEnd` event.

```
onDragEnded(event) {
  let element = event.source.getRootElement();
  let boundingClientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  let parentPosition = this.getPosition(element);
  console.log('x: ' + (boundingClientRect.x - parentPosition.left), 'y: ' + (boundingClientRect.y - parentPosition.top));        
}

getPosition(el) {
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  while(el && !isNaN(el.offsetLeft) && !isNaN(el.offsetTop)) {
    x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
    y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return { top: y, left: x };
}
```

I have modified the stackblitz to log the x and y coordinates of the rectangle being moved [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-6-cjn4xp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

To solve the problem where the rectangle to be moved is contained in another element, we use the `getPosition` function (which has been taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element/39149560#39149560) stackoverflow post) to retrieve the top/left values of the containing element, which then lets us calculate the x/y coordinates correctly.

Comment: This is really close, I think.  The problem is that x and y are relative to the window, not the bounding container (even though the name suggests otherwise).  See https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-6-fccbia to show that when the box is moved to the top left it is not at 0, 0.  Where did you find documentation for `getBoundingClientRect()`?

Comment: It's from the MDN documentation on Element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: Okay I think I found a solution for your problem, check this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-6-xyszfl?file=app/app.component.ts, it is based on this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element/39149560#39149560

Comment: Is it possible set the position?